# Fails to read GMAIL inbox with "Invalid credentials (Failure)" when setting up ImapFlow

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, imap, imapflow

I try to read a GMAIL inbox using NodeJS. I created a GMAIL account, I set up a google cloud OAuth application to get ClientID, ClientSecret and refresh token, as it is not possible to read GMAIL account inbox without these credentials.

I have this script:

```
import xoauth2 from 'xoauth2';
import { ImapFlow } from 'imapflow';

const xoauth2Gen = xoauth2.createXOAuth2Generator({
    user: 'MY_EMAIL@gmail.com',
    clientId: 'XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    clientSecret: 'XXXX',
    refreshToken: 'XXXXXXX',
});

const PreTestsAuthentication = async () => {
    const xoauth2Token = await new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
        xoauth2Gen.getToken((error: unknown, token: string) => {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            }

            return resolve(token);
        });
    });

    const client = new ImapFlow({
        host: 'imap.gmail.com',
        port: 993,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: 'MY_EMAIL@gmail.com',
            pass: 'XXXXX',
            accessToken: xoauth2Token,
        },
    });

    await client.connect();

    await client.logout();
};

export default PreTestsAuthentication;
```

When I run this code, I get an error:

```
{
  "response": "3 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)",
  "responseStatus": "NO",
  "responseText": "Invalid credentials (Failure)",
  "serverResponseCode": "AUTHENTICATIONFAILED",
  "authenticationFailed": true,
  "oauthError": {
    "status": "invalid_request",
    "scope": "https://mail.google.com/"
  }
}
```

This is the way I got the refresh token:

- I followed this guide: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/nodejs
- I got the refresh token by using this code block from the guide above:

```
const client = await authenticate({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'],
    keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
  });
```

Now, in the client object, there is a `refresh_token` key and I got its value. Then I used this value in code I shared above, where I'm having the issue.

Comment: first off xoauth2 only supports the https://mail.google.com/ scope.

Comment: The refresh token created with the quickstart has a `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly` scope, but your script requests a `https://mail.google.com/` scope. The scopes have to match or you will get an error. Try changing the scope in the quickstart to `https://mail.google.com/` and use the token you get from it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use app password instead of account password:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833